# How do i use $session_get_cookie_params?

Tags: php, cookies

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php

How do I use this `session_get_cookie_params()`? I've tried

```
$session_get_cookie_params['session.cookie_lifetime'] does nothing
```

although

```
INI_Get('session.cookie_lifetime') shows 0

var_dump($session_get_cookie_params) gives NULL
```

Should I set before I try to get them?

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php

Comment: @Mark I think the OP already did.

Answer (score 6):

`session_get_cookie_params` is a *function*, not a variable. You use it like this:

```
$cookie_params = session_get_cookie_params();
echo $cookie_params['lifetime'];
```